# Weird display behaviour when selecting tableview row

Tags: swift, uikit, tableview

I have this table view, that populates through Core Data. Everything looks fine, even when scrolling, until I press and hold any row - then that row distorts like in the second image below.
[image: normal view]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48691076551_0dbbfb69dc.jpg))</sub>

[image: weird distortion]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48691243292_71384579e9.jpg))</sub>

Here's the code to display the tableview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    animateBackground(colors)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.fetchData(fetchedResultsController as! NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard fetchedResultsController.sections?.count != nil else { return 0 }
    return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard fetchedResultsController.sections != nil else { return 0 }
    let data = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
    return data.numberOfObjects
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SkillCell", for: indexPath) as! SkillCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: SkillCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let skill = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.skill = skill
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }
```

}

From the code above, everything looks normal, yet this distortion occurs. Please help me to see why and how to stop it happening.

Comment: It’s not distorting, the cell is highlighting when you tap it.

Comment: change TableViewCell Property  SelectionStyle from the Storyboard  as none.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment suggests, it's just a visual effect called `selectionStyle` of your `UITableViewCell`. Inside your `cellForRowAt indexPath` method, you can disable it like:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! MyCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none // this removes the effect.
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems like something so simple, yet I had no idea...

Answer (score 0):

yes you should set tableView selection style to none.
1.Select the tableview in storyboard in the right panel set selection style to none.
or 
2.in your tableview cellforrow method set

```
tableView.selectionstyle = none
```